# Dynamically adding new row in Swing GridLayout - How to enable Scrolling

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've added rows dynamically to a grid view. When the number of rows are more than what can be displayed on the screen, the remainder content is hidden. How to enable scrolling to view the remainder of the undisplayed rows ?

```
    JPanel billItemsPanel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout billItemsLayout = new GridLayout(0,6);
    billItemsLayout.setVgap(20);
    billItemsPanel.setLayout(billItemsLayout);
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Mobile Number"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new TextField(20));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label(""));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label(""));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label(""));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label(""));  

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    billItemsPanel.add(new TextField("Hi SKU"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Hi Title"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Hi Type"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new TextField("Hi Qty"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Hi Price"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Hi Amount"));

    billItemsPanel.add(new TextField("Bye SKU"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Bye Title"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Bye Type"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new TextField("Bye Qty"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Bye Price"));
    billItemsPanel.add(new Label("Bye Amount"));
}
```

Comment: post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Scrolling is provided by a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer : JScrollPane cannot be added to a Layout. In my application, the GridLayout is used group related items. So, I will have to use JScrollPane(billItemsLayout) which is incorrect. How do I go about it ?

Comment: @user3388324 Set your billItemsPanel as the scroll panes view component and then add your scroll pane to the previous parent and use what ever layout manager you like, like BorderLayout for example

Answer (score 1):

wrap it in a new JScrollPane()

Comment: @Ofrek Ron: I'm not able to understand how to add the JScrollPane(GridLayout). It is incorrect and code won't compile. What is that I'm missing ?

Comment: *"..how to add the JScrollPane(GridLayout)."* should be more like, `new JScrollPane(new JPanel(new GridLayout()))` but if you need further help, post an MCVE with copy/pasted compiler or run-time output.